# Nodejs imagemin how do I pass in the list of files to process

Tags: node.js, imagemin

Trying to get imagemin to work in Nodejs. This is my code:

```
var imagemin = require('imagemin');
var imageminPngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant');
var PNGImages = ['images/image1.png', 'images/image2.png'];

imagemin(PNGImages, 'build', {
    plugins: [
        imageminPngquant({
            quality: '65-80'
        })
    ]
});
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
(node:22744) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ArgumentError: Expected argument to be of type `array` but received type `string`
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.
imageminPngquant was throwing the error due to the 65-80 in the quality setting and not because of the PNGImages array.

:)

Answer (score 0):

Pass Quality as below

```
imageminPngquant({
            quality: [65, 80]
        })
```